# Filter from Android onCreateOptionsMenu Item

Tags: android

I want to add filter button to my onCreateOptionsMenu. When button was clicked i need to show layout with checkboxes and apply button.

Only way that i know how to do this - start new activity from onOptionsItemSelected and do all operations there. But is there more efficient way? Without leaving current activity. Something like pop-up window etc.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> You can do it By Using this Material Dialog
>   https://github.com/drakeet/MaterialDialog Library and Below code, Just
>   put the gravity of Dialog TOP|RIGHT.

```
private void showMaterialDialog() {

        final ArrayAdapter<String> arrayAdapter = new ArrayAdapter<String>(this,
                android.R.layout.simple_list_item_single_choice);
        for (Card card : cards) {
            arrayAdapter.add(card.getName());
        }


         alert = new MaterialDialog(this);
        View mView = getLayoutInflater().inflate(R.layout.custom_view_virtual_card, null);
        ListView listView = (ListView) mView.findViewById(R.id.listView);
        listView.setAdapter(arrayAdapter);
        listView.setChoiceMode(ListView.CHOICE_MODE_SINGLE);
        AppCompatButton btnCancel = (AppCompatButton) mView.findViewById(R.id.btnCancel);
        AppCompatButton btnOk = (AppCompatButton) mView.findViewById(R.id.btnOk);

        btnOk.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {
                startAsyncForRequestVirtualCard(selectedCardTypeId);
                alert.dismiss();
            }
        });
        btnCancel.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {
                alert.dismiss();
            }
        });
        listView.setOnItemClickListener(new AdapterView.OnItemClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onItemClick(AdapterView<?> parent, View view, int position, long id) {
                selectedCardTypeId = cards.get(position).getId();
                Log.d("request", cards.get(position).getId() + " " + cards.get(position).getName());
            }
        });

        alert.setView(mView);
        alert.show();

    }
```

**custom_view_virtual.xml**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:background="@color/white"
    android:orientation="vertical">

    <TextView
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_margin="10dp"
        android:text="Select Card Type"
        android:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearanceSmall"
        android:textColor="@color/colorAccent" />

    <View
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="0.25dp"
        android:background="@color/divider" />


    <ListView
        android:id="@+id/listView"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_weight="1"
        android:layout_marginTop="5dp"
        android:divider="@color/transparent"
        android:theme="@style/ProgressBarStyle"/>

    <LinearLayout
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_gravity="right"
        android:layout_marginRight="10dp">

        <android.support.v7.widget.AppCompatButton
            android:id="@+id/btnCancel"
            style="@style/Widget.AppCompat.Button.Borderless"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_marginRight="5dp"
            android:text="@string/cancel"
            android:textColor="@color/colorAccent"
            android:textSize="15sp" />

        <android.support.v7.widget.AppCompatButton
            android:id="@+id/btnOk"
            style="@style/Widget.AppCompat.Button.Borderless"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:text="@string/ok"
            android:textColor="@color/colorAccent"
            android:textSize="15sp" />
    </LinearLayout>
</LinearLayout>
```

Answer (score 0):

Don't create a new activity instead create a new java class in that apply your sorting logic to filter the content and when your button is pressed that activity should return all your sorted content using List class or ArrayList class or anything else then display it.

Comment: But pressing button can't sort anything, because user must press filter button - > then check/uncheck checkboxes (options) and press apply. Only after that i'll know how to sort.

Comment: where are the checkboxes present in the same layout??

Comment: @sumit this is my question. Where to put this checkboxes if not in another activity? I don't have any space for it in my current activity.

Comment: put them in the same activity and keep their visibility gone and when the user clicks the button make them visible and do whatever you want to do with them

Comment: Use another activity as a pop-up for your sorting when click on filter button.