# Custom Adapter for Alert dialog android

Tags: android, dialog, android-alertdialog

i want to make a alert dialog that look like this.

[image: Installed Apps with icons]

and there is my code

```
    final item[] items = {

            new item("Email", android.R.drawable.ic_menu_add),
            new item("Facebook", android.R.drawable.ic_menu_delete),

    };



    ListAdapter adapter = new ArrayAdapter<item>(
            this,
            android.R.layout.select_dialog_item,
            android.R.id.text1,
            items){

        @NonNull
        @Override
        public View getView(int position, @Nullable View convertView, @NonNull ViewGroup parent)
        {
            View v = super.getView(position, convertView, parent);
            TextView tv = (TextView)v.findViewById(android.R.id.text1);



            tv.setCompoundDrawablesWithIntrinsicBounds(items[position].icon, 0, 0, 0);

            int dp5 = (int) (5 * getResources().getDisplayMetrics().density + 0.5f);
            tv.setCompoundDrawablePadding(dp5);

            return v;
        }
    };


    new AlertDialog.Builder(this)
            .setTitle("Share Appliction")
            .setNegativeButton("asddasd", new DialogInterface.OnClickListener()
            {
                @Override
                public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog, int which)
                {

                }
            })
            .setAdapter(adapter, new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {
                public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog, int item) {
                    Log.d("Fsdf","Sfss");
                }
            }).show();
```

and item class there

```
public class item
```

{

```
public final String text;
public final int icon;

public item(String text, Integer icon) {
    this.text = text;
    this.icon = icon;
}
@Override
public String toString() {
    return text;
}
```

}

now i don't know how to put item in item array each time that i get from package manager using async task it is there

Comment: `ArrayAdapter<item>(
            this,
            android.R.layout.select_dialog_item,
            android.R.id.text1,
            items)`

you initialize these in constructor and inflate them in `getView`.

Comment: can you tell in detail please

Answer (score 0):

> try my this answer, i think it will help you a lot....if you fine any
>   problem then let me know that.

[Filter from Android onCreateOptionsMenu Item](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44476177/filter-from-android-oncreateoptionsmenu-item/44477352#44477352)